# Table Cell Index Problems in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

The following line is giving me trouble in IE8, while working in Chrome and Firefox:

```
this.column = header_index[this.parentNode.rowIndex + "-" + this.cellIndex];
```

IE8 returns "unexpected call to method or property access". I tried a fix recommended elsewhere, using `getCellIndex(this)` instead of `this.cellIndex`, and added:

```
function getCellIndex(aCell) {
    aRow = aCell.parentNode;
    for (i = 0; i != aRow.cells.length; i++) {
        if (aRow.cells[i] == aCell) return i;
    }
}
```

...and was told that "cells.length is null or not an object".

Any recommendations on how to proceed would be appreciated. Relevant part of the function below, trouble is on line 6:

```
$tableHeaders = $(c.selectorHeaders, table)
            .wrapInner("<div class='tablesorter-header-inner' />")
            .each(function(index) {
                $t = $(this);
                ch = c.headers[index];
                this.column = header_index[this.parentNode.rowIndex + "-" + this.cellIndex];
                this.order = formatSortingOrder( ts.getData($t, ch, 'sortInitialOrder') || c.sortInitialOrder ) ? [1,0,2] : [0,1,2];
                this.count = -1; // set to -1 because clicking on the header automatically adds one
                if (ts.getData($t, ch, 'sorter') === 'false') { this.sortDisabled = true; }
                this.lockedOrder = false;
                lock = ts.getData($t, ch, 'lockedOrder') || false;
                if (typeof(lock) !== 'undefined' && lock !== false) {
                    this.order = this.lockedOrder = formatSortingOrder(lock) ? [1,1,1] : [0,0,0];
                }
```

Comment: A solution would be to use jQuery to deal with this incompatibilities. jQuery has a index() function which seems to be what you need.

Comment: @dystroy: `rows` and `cells` work fine in IE. jQuery probably wouldn't be much help.

Comment: Some HTML would help here.

Comment: Actually already hip-deep in jQuery. Edited.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why not replacing `this.cellIndex` with `$(this).index()` ?